# How do I speed up polyline re-rendering when panning with MKMap?

Tags: objective-c, swift, mapkit

[Polyline at correct size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJDE3.jpg)
[Polyline re-rendering too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5S64.png)

#### Description:

I'm placing a polyline on a MKMap, after zooming in, the panning action will show an oversized pixilated polyline for a period of time till it re-renders it to the correct size.

#### Solutions I've tried:

- Other SOF posts have given solutions to subclass `MKPolylineRenderer` and set it to a static size. This solution means that the line is either too small to see on large maps or too big for small ones
- I've tried making it a solid polyline, if there is any improvement then it's marginal.
- I have looked into `func applyStrokeProperties(to: CGContext, atZoomScale: MKZoomScale)` to resize the whole polyline on each zoom change. Creating the CGContext proved to be above my current skill level and it's unclear if doing this will create performance issues with zooming

#### Code Samples:

````
    convenience init(polyline: MKPolyline) {
        self.init(points: polyline.points(), count: polyline.pointCount)
    }

    @objc
    func renderer() -> MKPolylineRenderer {
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: self)
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = .black
        polylineRenderer.lineDashPattern = [0, 10]

        return polylineRenderer
    }
}```

and implementation:
```- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

    // Return a KML renderer if there is one
    MKOverlayRenderer *kmlRenderer = [SRMapViewController kmlRendererForKmlOverlay:overlay];
    if (kmlRenderer) {
        return kmlRenderer;
    }

    // Return a Route renderer if there is one
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[RoutePolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [((RoutePolyline *)overlay) renderer];
        return renderer;
    }

    // Return an MKPolyline if we have a UserLocation path
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineRenderer *userLocationPathRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        userLocationPathRenderer.lineWidth = USER_LOCATION_PATH_LINE_WIDTH;
        UIColor *userColor = [self colorForUserLocationLine:overlay];   // color for the user of the UserLocation
        userLocationPathRenderer.strokeColor = userColor;
        return userLocationPathRenderer;
    }

    // find which area is being rendered and return the renderer for it
    MKOverlayRenderer *renderer;
    for (NSString *areaId in self.visibleAreaDict) {
        MKPolygon *areaOverlay = [self overlayForAreaWithId:areaId];
        if (overlay == areaOverlay) {
            renderer = [self rendererForAreaWithId:areaId];
            break;
        }
    }

    NSAssert(renderer, @"ERROR: self.visibleAreaDict is missing a renderer for overlay %@! It should already be created before this method is called", overlay);
    return renderer;
}```

Desired solutions:
 - Hopefully an easy fix to speed up the re-render
 - A good third party library for the polyline
 - A work around to make the problem less visible

Undesired solutions:
 - switch to Google Maps

Thanks!!
````

Comment: Check performance without line dashing. That is super CPU expensive

Comment: Hi Warren, I've done that, I have a couple of vids showing the difference but I can't post them on here.
After testing them, it doesn't seem like there is a noticeable difference

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of research it turned out that you can't speed it up. Apple maps uses it's own custom renderer which is far more performant. For the rest of us, we just need to work with the lag.